# How to get JSON array on web service via Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have a .net web service that returns JSON Array. I watched some tutorials on YouTube but it didn't work. My web service is not getting any parameters. Just returns JSON Array.

Here is my Interface code :

```
public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:50553/ClientControl.asmx";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("?op=btGetTable")
    Call<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>> getRecords();
}
```

Here is my values that returns from JSON and getters for it.

```
public class WebServiceDenemeKayitlar {
        private String KODU;
        private String ACIKLAMA;
        private boolean KAPALI_FL;
        private String TARIH;
        private short DURUM;
        private int TUTAR;

    public WebServiceDenemeKayitlar(String KODU, String ACIKLAMA, boolean KAPALI_FL, String TARIH, int TUTAR, short DURUM) {
        this.KODU = KODU;
        this.ACIKLAMA = ACIKLAMA;
        this.KAPALI_FL = KAPALI_FL;
        this.TARIH = TARIH;

        this.TUTAR = TUTAR;
        this.DURUM = DURUM;
    }
    public String getKODU() {
        return KODU;
    }

    public String getACIKLAMA() {
        return ACIKLAMA;
    }

    public boolean isKAPALI_FL() {
        return KAPALI_FL;
    }

    public String getTARIH() {
        return TARIH;
    }

    public int getTUTAR() {
        return TUTAR;
    }

    public short getDURUM() {
        return DURUM;
    }

}
```

And here is my calling in Activity

```
   public void InitData(){
        String path = "http://localhost:50553/ClientControl.asmx";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>> call = api.getRecords();
        Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>> call, Response<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>> response) {
                List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar> kayitlar = response.body();

                for(WebServiceDenemeKayitlar kayit : kayitlar){
                    Log.d("KODU" , kayit.getKODU());
                    Log.d("ACIKLAMA" , kayit.getACIKLAMA());
                    Log.d("KAPALI_FL" , String.valueOf(kayit.isKAPALI_FL()));
                    Log.d("TARIH" , kayit.getTARIH());
                    Log.d("TUTAR" , String.valueOf(kayit.getTUTAR()));
                    Log.d("DURUM" , String.valueOf(kayit.getDURUM()));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WebServiceDenemeKayitlar>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I realized something and it is about the base URL. When i post the URL that retrofit tries to call to browser , it shows error about the bad calling. My WebService's link is like that : `http://localhost:50553/ClientControl.asmx?op=btGetTable` How can i call this service via Retrofit ? Or do you have any suggestion about which library should i use ?

Comment: do you know what `localhost` is?

Comment: When i replace it with my pc's IP it is still same.

Comment: If you are with local host then you need to run in emulator! It will not work in real device

Comment: This is my first time with Retrofit btw. What do you recommend ?

Comment: firstly make sure that your server is available from your ANdroid device

Comment: @Piyush , I am running this app on Emulator. What i have to do to work it on Device ?

Comment: in emulator you need to use specific IP for the emulator to access the PC. In real device you need to use your PC's LAN ip if they both are in the same network, or the outer IP if they are in the different networks. You also have to have standalone dedicated IP to access from other network

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  Thanks for your answers. Web service is running on my computer and Visual Studio. It is reachable. When i debug the app with the above code , logcat says baseURL must end with "/" . When i add "/" to end of the BASE_URL it says  java.util.List.iterator() on a null object reference. Looks like i am missing something  to declare. And i am writing my PC's IP for now. But i am going to take this WebService into the server.